# Javascript if variable is not null

Tags: javascript

`if (typeof (location.x != null) {`

Using the above I run into the follow error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of null`

I have tried `console.log(location.x)` which results in an example with `null`

Comment: May I ask where do you run this code?

Comment: using `location` tends to be a bad variable name because of `window.location`. One miss `var` and your "truthy" check will be true.

Comment: @epascarello—then why is it *null*? BTW, [*typeof*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.3) always returns a string which is never `== null`.

Comment: @RobG: window.location and the local variable location, in this context, are different.  Your confusion is precisely the reason for  epascarello's comment.

Comment: @ChrisCM—try assigning *null* to *window.location*.

Comment: @RobG: What epascarello is saying, is that if you forget "var" in your "var location" declaration, you will be using the window.location value, which since location in this case is null, is clearly not intended, and therefore, poor style.

Comment: @ChrisCM: `window.location` should never be null in a browser. I think that's RobG's point.

Comment: @epascarello is 100% correct about the variable name being unwise, RobG makes a very important point (for the OP) about typeof returning a string.

Comment: You're missing a closing parenthesis in your code. Can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: @ChrisCM—if the OP forgets "var" and assigns something to *location* the error will be pretty obvious. ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
if (location && location.x) {

}
```

Comment: hopefully x is not a falsey value.

Comment: in this case  you use location.x!=undefined for condition in if statement

Comment: `typeof myVariable !== 'undefined` is safer IMO -- no terrorist jQuery plugin can redefine `undefined` on you if you use typeof.

Answer (score 2):

You can just do:

```
if (location && location.x) {

}
```

Comment: Still results with `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of null`

Comment: hopefully x is not a falsey value.

Answer (score 1):

The x attribute can't be reached because your location variable is null